# Vertical alignment of responsive images of unknown height using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, layout, responsive-design

I'm trying to layout images vertically aligned bottom (see picture below) in a responsive layout with images of unknown heights.

The images are scaled to fit the width of the column, but the heights vary and I cannot find out what it is in advance.

[image]

Unfortunately at the moment the closest I have managed to get is this

[image]

I'd really like to avoid using javascript if possible, because the number of columns will change depending on the screen width using media queries - which will make the javascript more complex.

The CSS I am using at the moment is

```
#catalogue-items {
  @include clearfix;
  margin: 40px 0;

  .catalogue-item {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4%;
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    p {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      padding: 0.5em;
    }

    &:nth-child(4n + 1) {
      clear:left;
    }
  }
}
```

With the nth-child selector changing using media queries.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: show us the your code on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: sorry Champ, didn't see this & has been answered now anyway - thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it using `display: inline-block`

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img width="50" height="100" src="/img/logo.png"/><br/>
        Description
    <li>
    <li>
        <img width="50" height="125" src="/img/logo.png"/><br/>
        Description
    <li>
    <li>
        <img width="50" height="75" src="/img/logo.png"/><br/>
        Description
    <li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin-left: -10px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

img {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaHpc/1/)

Comment: wow... thanks! I thought that would need specifying the height & width for it to work, but seems to work fine without. Must remember to use inline-block :)